# 2 CSS files loads one after another

Tags: html, css

So, I have 2 CSS files for a HTML page. When the page loads, it shows the styles of the first CSS page and then loads the 2nd CSS file. So, for that one second, my page looks a little different then what it is supposed to be. How can we avoid it?

For example, I have bootstrap.css and my custom css. It always shows the bootstrap.css styles for that one second before loading my custom.css.

Comment: Please post your code we cant help you without it.

Comment: use `!important` in your custom.css

Comment: @SachiTekina yes I did add. Should I add for every single styles?

Comment: Don't use `!important`. That isn't a solution, and it's bad practice to exploit it.

Comment: @fubar Then how do we solve this?

Comment: It sounds like your web server is potentially just slow to respond with your custom CSS. Is it a large file? Are you minifying your assets? But you could combine the Bootstrap and custom CSS into a single payload, use an `@import` statement to load Bootstrap CSS from your custom CSS, use better hosting, if it's slow to respond to requests. More information would be useful.

Comment: @SachiTekina, That is [bad advice](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/11/the-important-css-declaration-how-and-when-to-use-it/#when-should-important-be-used). `!important` should only be used as an absolute, last ditch, solution. **NEVER** as the first solution.

Comment: @JonP Well, without much information given by the OP. One I can think of is, add another modifier on the element you want to customize.

Comment: You're experiencing FOUC because you're loading stylesheets **after** building DOM. Load all your stylesheets in `<head>` and it won't happen. DOM building does not start until CSSOM is built and it's built out of all `<style>`s and `<link>`s in `<head>`.

Comment: "Then how do we solve this?" ... we start by you giving us enough info to help you. Please include an example of your HTML structure that illustrates the problem in the form of a [MCVE]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[FOUC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_of_unstyled_content) doesn't happen because you're loading stylesheets in a particular order.

It happens because you load CSS after DOM has already been (partially) built. To prevent it, do not load CSS in `<body>`, but in `<head>`. In any order you want.

If you do place style rules or references in `<body>`, make sure they're placed above the affected elements.

Answer (score 2):

Hard without seeing your code, but if you don't have much CSS in your custom file, I'd suggest just adding it to the bottom of your first CSS file

Answer (score -2):

You can use JQuery to do that.

```js
$(function () {
setTimeout(function(){
 $('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/style_2.css">').appendTo("body");
}, 3000);
});
```

Change the time to appending second CSS style.
Hope that will help you.